# Unable to use DatePicker choose box when using TextFormatter

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I want to create three(3) sets of Combobox (Year, Month, Day).
The `Combobox Day` should only be enabled until the Combobox Month and Year were filed correctly, and values should be synchronized based on the given month and year. (This means that it should check for leap years).

Here is what I have so far, I have a hint that I should use bindings and/or listeners to do this but struggle to do so.

```
public class Testing extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final JFXComboBox<Month> cbMonths = new JFXComboBox<>();
        final JFXComboBox<Integer> cbYears = new JFXComboBox<>();
        final JFXComboBox<Integer> cbDays = new JFXComboBox<>();

        // Month Values
        cbMonths.getItems().setAll(Month.values());
        // Year Values
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) ;
             i >= (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) -35) ; i--)
        {
            cbYears.getItems().add(i);
        }

        // NOTE: will cause NPE
        //       I want to insert this code only when cbMonth and cbYears has a value
        YearMonth numberOfDays = YearMonth.of(cbYear.getValue(), cbMonth.getValue());
        for (int i = 1 ; i >= numberOfDays.lengthOfMonth() ; i ++) {
            cbDays.getItems().add(i);
        }

        final HBox root = new HBox(cbMonth, cbYear, cbDays);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setSpacing(10.0);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
```

### EDIT

Having a lack of time, I tried other options.

### OPTION 1:

As @Zephyr points out, I switch to a date picker and set it to `editable`. I tried to override some of its default settings to come up with my desire output. But I notice that whenever I use TextFormatter I was unable to pick dates on the DatePicker choice box. Here is the sample code

```
public class DatePickerFinal extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final String DATE_REGEX = "(0[1-9]|1[012])\\s(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\s((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2})";
        final DateTimeFormatter SHOW_DATE = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        final DateTimeFormatter ENTER_DATE = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM dd yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        final LocalDate TODAY = LocalDate.now();

        final JFXDatePicker DATE_PICKER = new JFXDatePicker();

        // Disable some dates
        DATE_PICKER.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(DatePicker datePicker) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate localDate, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(localDate, b);
                        setDisable(b || localDate.compareTo(TODAY) > 0 || localDate.compareTo(TODAY.minusYears(45)) < 0);
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        // Add StringConverter to make it more readable,
        // and also rejecting disable dates inputted by the user
        DATE_PICKER.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(LocalDate localDate) {
                if (localDate == null) {
                    return "";
                } else if (localDate.isAfter(TODAY) || localDate.isBefore(TODAY.minusYears(45))) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return SHOW_DATE.format(localDate);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String s) {
                return (s == null || s.isEmpty()) ? null : LocalDate.parse(s, ENTER_DATE);
            }
        });


        // Then I want to manage user input so that they can only enter digits to the date picker
        // then format it accordingly.

        DATE_PICKER.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<Object>(change -> {
            String enteredText = change.getText();
            if((enteredText.matches("[\\d]+")) || change.isDeleted()) {
                final int oldTextLength = change.getControlText().length();
                int newTextLength = change.getControlNewText().length();

                if (newTextLength < oldTextLength) return change;
                switch (newTextLength) {
                    case 2 :
                    case 5 :
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(enteredText);
                        stringBuilder.append(" ");
                        change.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        newTextLength++;
                        break;
                    case 11 :
                        return null;
                }
                change.setCaretPosition(newTextLength);
                change.setAnchor(newTextLength);
                return change;
            }
            return null;
        }));

        
        // Add some validators where if the user input was valid or not. The below code was still in progress though.
        RequiredFieldValidator requiredFieldValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        requiredFieldValidator.setMessage("Field Should Not Be Empty");
        RegexValidator regexValidator = new RegexValidator("MM DD YYYY");
        regexValidator.setRegexPattern(DATE_REGEX);
        DATE_PICKER.setValidators(regexValidator);
        DATE_PICKER.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean t1) {
                if (t1) {
                    DATE_PICKER.validate();
                }
            }
        });


        DATE_PICKER.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String t1) {
                if (!DATE_PICKER.getEditor().getText().matches(DATE_REGEX)) {
                    DATE_PICKER.validate();
                }
            }
        });


        VBox root = new VBox(20, DATE_PICKER, new JFXButton("Button"));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Aside from being editable, I also want the user to be able to just click and/or pick dates from the choice box. I hope someone could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: a) _I have a hint that I should use bindings and/or listeners_ good direction :) Now apply it, start small (f.i. with 2 combos) and extend when that's working - when stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and how it's not working as expected b) don't mix old (Calendar) and new date/time (YearMonth) api

Comment: On the off chance you might be doing too much work, JavaFX also includes a `DatePicker` control that might be helpful for you.

Comment: java naming conventions, please ..

Comment: .. and don't understand what you are trying here, with the many conficting (borderline, concededly ;) collaborators: if you use a textFormatter a) it's the formatter's job to validate b) the converter used in the picker must be the same as the converter in the formatter. Also: don't use regex to validate date/time, instead use an appropriate (locale-aware) Format

Comment: @kleopatra, sorry for that and thank you, I'll try to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @kleopatra's help. My solution is to create a class responsible for parsing the date selected by the user on the DatePickers default choice box. Furthermore, the date picker is set to editable so that the user can also edit it manually. However, there is a restriction where a user can **ONLY** insert numerical value when editing manually, also I wanted to make sure that the user should input only valid dates.

---

### MCVE

```
public class DatePickerFinal extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final String DATE_OF_BIRTH_REGEX
                = "(0[1-9]|1[012])\\s(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\\s((19|2[0-9])[0-9]{2})";
        final DateTimeFormatter showingDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        final DateTimeFormatter inputtedDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM dd yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        final LocalDate dateToday = LocalDate.now();

        final JFXDatePicker datePicker = new JFXDatePicker();

        // Disable some dates
        datePicker.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(DatePicker datePicker) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate localDate, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(localDate, b);
                        setDisable(b || localDate.compareTo(dateToday) > 0 || localDate.compareTo(dateToday.minusYears(45)) < 0);
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        // Add StringConverter to make it more readable,
        // and also rejecting disable dates inputted by the user
        datePicker.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(LocalDate localDate) {
                if (localDate == null) {
                    return "";
                } else if (localDate.isAfter(dateToday) || localDate.isBefore(dateToday.minusYears(45))) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return showingDateFormat.format(localDate);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public LocalDate fromString(String s) {
                return (s == null || s.isEmpty()) ? null : LocalDate.parse(s, inputtedDateFormat);
            }
        });

        // Add a validator
        RequiredFieldValidator requiredFieldValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        requiredFieldValidator.setMessage("Enter with the format\nMM DD YYYY");
        datePicker.setValidators(requiredFieldValidator);

        // Format the user's input field
        datePicker.getEditor().setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
            String textEntered = change.getText();

            DateValidator validator;

            if (change.isContentChange()) {

                validator = new DateValidator(change.getControlNewText(), showingDateFormat);
                if (!validator.isValid()) {
                    datePicker.validate();
                } else {
                    datePicker.resetValidation();
                    return change;
                }

                if (textEntered.matches("\\D+")) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    final int oldLength = change.getControlText().length();
                    int newLength = change.getControlNewText().length();
                    if (newLength < oldLength) return change;

                    if (newLength == 2 || newLength == 5) {
                        change.setText(textEntered + " ");
                        newLength++;
                    } else if (newLength == 11) {
                        validator = new DateValidator(change.getControlNewText(), inputtedDateFormat);
                        if (!validator.isValid()) {
                            return null;
                        } else {
                            datePicker.resetValidation();
                        }
                    }

                    change.setCaretPosition(newLength);
                    change.setAnchor(newLength);
                }
            }

            return change;
        }));

        datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener((observableValue, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
            if (isFocused) {
                Platform.runLater(()-> {
                    datePicker.validate();
                    datePicker.getEditor().selectAll();
                });
            } else {
                datePicker.resetValidation();
            }
        });

        datePicker.getEditor().textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observableValue, String s, String t1) {
                if (t1.matches(DATE_OF_BIRTH_REGEX)) {
                    datePicker.resetValidation();
                }
            }
        });

        // Show picker choice box on MouseEvent
        datePicker.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> {
            datePicker.show();
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(50, datePicker, new JFXButton("Button"));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class DateValidator  {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter;
        String date;

        DateValidator (String date, DateTimeFormatter formatter) {
            this.date = date;
            this.formatter = formatter;
        }

        public boolean isValid() {
            try {
                LocalDate.parse(this.date, this.formatter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. obviously you put quite an effort into this, glad you found a solution :) But there are some fishy points (already mentioned the picker.converter != textFormatter.converter and  using regex to validate (not truely locale-aware, is it?) a) changing the editor's text in a listener to the textProperty (no-no-no generally) b) cell.updateItem not handling empty/null valued cellls (might not be as important as in other cell types, but being allowed is its contract :)

Comment: @kleopatra thanks :), I'll try to update this later on. Thanks for the assistance